# Keycloak authentication loops forever

Tags: spring, keycloak

For a Spring Boot project, I try to implement a simple authentication with Keycloak. I use the latest versions for both Spring and Keycloak.

When I try to access a protected page (eg. /c/page), the authentication runs into an infinite loop:

[image]

The application.properties content looks like this:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://k.lvh.me:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=Admin
keycloak.resource=skel
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.ssl-required=NONE
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true

server.port=8081

keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/c/*

logging.level.org.keycloak=TRACE
logging.level.org.jboss=DEBUG
```

It seems the roles are set correctly:

```
2020-09-06 01:03:55.578 TRACE 53009 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterUtils       : useResourceRoleMappings
2020-09-06 01:03:55.578 TRACE 53009 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterUtils       : Setting roles: 
2020-09-06 01:03:55.578 TRACE 53009 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterUtils       :    role: user
2020-09-06 01:03:55.578 TRACE 53009 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.k.a.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext : checking whether to refresh.
2020-09-06 01:03:55.578 DEBUG 53009 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User 'admin' invoking 'http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/55?state=e0ed8f7a-36ba-4649-acd5-f278a7fc142b&session_state=5e1dc9a5-dcd5-4c3b-bf1d-d01c52ec4f8e&code=9148280b-5572-47ea-b34a-9373fe5fd2da.5e1dc9a5-dcd5-4c3b-bf1d-d01c52ec4f8e.ef92caf8-e672-492d-9908-ca056828bac1' on client 'skel'
2020-09-06 01:03:55.578 DEBUG 53009 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : AUTHENTICATED
```

While looking at the logs, there is no much info:

```
2020-09-06 00:43:35.450 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/m
2020-09-06 00:43:35.453 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'skel'
2020-09-06 00:43:35.454 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-09-06 00:43:35.455 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-09-06 00:43:35.455 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret-jwt
2020-09-06 00:43:35.456 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-09-06 00:43:35.456 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-09-06 00:43:35.456 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret-jwt
2020-09-06 00:43:35.464 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : --> authenticate()
2020-09-06 00:43:35.464 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try bearer
2020-09-06 00:43:35.466 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try query parameter auth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.466 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try oauth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.476 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was no code
2020-09-06 00:43:35.476 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : redirecting to auth server
2020-09-06 00:43:35.477 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : callback uri: http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/m
2020-09-06 00:43:35.478 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Resolving URLs from http://k.lvh.me:8080/auth/realms/Admin/.well-known/openid-configuration
2020-09-06 00:43:35.811  INFO 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from http://k.lvh.me:8080/auth/realms/Admin/.well-known/openid-configuration
2020-09-06 00:43:35.820 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Sending redirect to login page: http://k.lvh.me:8080/auth/realms/admin/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=skel&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ff1.lvh.me%3A8081%2Fc%2Fm&state=061a62e3-fd33-4dd1-8f01-acf98804d0d7&login=true&scope=openid
2020-09-06 00:43:35.901 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/m?state=061a62e3-fd33-4dd1-8f01-acf98804d0d7&session_state=310ba1c8-a9d2-45bf-89cc-c7c602b6e71f&code=5aa7068e-a113-4992-a546-5c6f7a37b96e.310ba1c8-a9d2-45bf-89cc-c7c602b6e71f.ef92caf8-e672-492d-9908-ca056828bac1
2020-09-06 00:43:35.902 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : --> authenticate()
2020-09-06 00:43:35.902 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try bearer
2020-09-06 00:43:35.902 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try query parameter auth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.902 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try oauth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.902 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was a code, resolving
2020-09-06 00:43:35.903 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : checking state cookie for after code
2020-09-06 00:43:35.903 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : ** reseting application state cookie
2020-09-06 00:43:35.924 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Verifying tokens
2020-09-06 00:43:35.931 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   :        access_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJOdV81czU4TTVtdTR2U21KdGhsSE1VVXBPbk9OeTVwOVlKWmpBYjNVdm40In0.eyJqdGkiOiI1MTBjNTliYi1kYTVmLTQ2ZGUtYTU1OS1mMWE1MWY0ZmU3MmQiLCJleHAiOjE1OTkzNDYxMTUsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTk5MzQ1ODE1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vay5sdmgubWU6ODA4MC9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9hZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6ImFjY291bnQiLCJzdWIiOiIwN2MzNTU5MS04NTRmLTQ1ZWItYjMxZS0zYWViNDFlOTllZWYiLCJ0eXAiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJhenAiOiJza2VsIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTk5MzM5MDg3LCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiMzEwYmExYzgtYTlkMi00NWJmLTg5Y2MtYzdjNjAyYjZlNzFmIiwiYWNyIjoiMCIsImFsbG93ZWQtb3JpZ2lucyI6WyIqIl0sInJlYWxtX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJvZmZsaW5lX2FjY2VzcyIsInVtYV9hdXRob3JpemF0aW9uIiwidXNlciJdfSwicmVzb3VyY2VfYWNjZXNzIjp7ImFjY291bnQiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsibWFuYWdlLWFjY291bnQiLCJtYW5hZ2UtYWNjb3VudC1saW5rcyIsInZpZXctcHJvZmlsZSJdfX0sInNjb3BlIjoib3BlbmlkIHByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwicHJlZmVycmVkX3VzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4ifQ.signature
2020-09-06 00:43:35.931 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   :        id_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJOdV81czU4TTVtdTR2U21KdGhsSE1VVXBPbk9OeTVwOVlKWmpBYjNVdm40In0.eyJqdGkiOiIzOGUxZDY5MC1lZjZlLTQ4ZDAtYWRhOC1iNDM0OGM3MmEzZDIiLCJleHAiOjE1OTkzNDYxMTUsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTk5MzQ1ODE1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vay5sdmgubWU6ODA4MC9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9hZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6InNrZWwiLCJzdWIiOiIwN2MzNTU5MS04NTRmLTQ1ZWItYjMxZS0zYWViNDFlOTllZWYiLCJ0eXAiOiJJRCIsImF6cCI6InNrZWwiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1OTkzMzkwODcsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiIzMTBiYTFjOC1hOWQyLTQ1YmYtODljYy1jN2M2MDJiNmU3MWYiLCJhY3IiOiIwIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIn0.signature
2020-09-06 00:43:35.932 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   :        refresh_token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJjMjZjNmE5Ny1kYmU5LTQwMjktYjg2Zi0yNDk3ZjAyYmNmMWIifQ.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.signature
2020-09-06 00:43:35.952 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Going to send request to retrieve new set of realm public keys for client skel
2020-09-06 00:43:35.961 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Realm public keys successfully retrieved for client skel. New kids: [Nu_5s58M5mu4vSmJthlHMUUpOnONy5p9YJZjAb3Uvn4]
2020-09-06 00:43:35.969 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Token Verification succeeded!
2020-09-06 00:43:35.969 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : successful authenticated
2020-09-06 00:43:35.970 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext : checking whether to refresh.
2020-09-06 00:43:35.970 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterUtils       : useResourceRoleMappings
2020-09-06 00:43:35.970 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterUtils       : Setting roles: 
2020-09-06 00:43:35.976 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext : checking whether to refresh.
2020-09-06 00:43:35.976 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User 'admin' invoking 'http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/m?state=061a62e3-fd33-4dd1-8f01-acf98804d0d7&session_state=310ba1c8-a9d2-45bf-89cc-c7c602b6e71f&code=5aa7068e-a113-4992-a546-5c6f7a37b96e.310ba1c8-a9d2-45bf-89cc-c7c602b6e71f.ef92caf8-e672-492d-9908-ca056828bac1' on client 'skel'
2020-09-06 00:43:35.976 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : AUTHENTICATED
2020-09-06 00:43:35.981 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/m
2020-09-06 00:43:35.981 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : --> authenticate()
2020-09-06 00:43:35.982 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try bearer
2020-09-06 00:43:35.982 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try query parameter auth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.982 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try oauth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.982 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was no code
2020-09-06 00:43:35.982 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : redirecting to auth server
2020-09-06 00:43:35.982 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : callback uri: http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/m
2020-09-06 00:43:35.983 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Sending redirect to login page: http://k.lvh.me:8080/auth/realms/admin/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=skel&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ff1.lvh.me%3A8081%2Fc%2Fm&state=e73199ad-2fc6-450c-a85b-5fdd1da41b3a&login=true&scope=openid
2020-09-06 00:43:35.997 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://f1.lvh.me:8081/c/m?state=e73199ad-2fc6-450c-a85b-5fdd1da41b3a&session_state=310ba1c8-a9d2-45bf-89cc-c7c602b6e71f&code=4fd237d0-590d-4b19-a74f-cc8c5d6f6bb2.310ba1c8-a9d2-45bf-89cc-c7c602b6e71f.ef92caf8-e672-492d-9908-ca056828bac1
2020-09-06 00:43:35.998 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : --> authenticate()
2020-09-06 00:43:35.998 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try bearer
2020-09-06 00:43:35.998 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try query parameter auth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.998 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try oauth
2020-09-06 00:43:35.998 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was a code, resolving
2020-09-06 00:43:35.998 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : checking state cookie for after code
2020-09-06 00:43:35.998 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : ** reseting application state cookie
2020-09-06 00:43:36.012 DEBUG 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Verifying tokens
2020-09-06 00:43:36.012 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   :        access_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJOdV81czU4TTVtdTR2U21KdGhsSE1VVXBPbk9OeTVwOVlKWmpBYjNVdm40In0.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.signature
2020-09-06 00:43:36.012 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   :        id_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJOdV81czU4TTVtdTR2U21KdGhsSE1VVXBPbk9OeTVwOVlKWmpBYjNVdm40In0.eyJqdGkiOiI2Njk2YTViMC0wNDg0LTQ3OTUtOTM2Mi1hZDU2MThkMDQ5OWQiLCJleHAiOjE1OTkzNDYxMTYsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTk5MzQ1ODE2LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vay5sdmgubWU6ODA4MC9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9hZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6InNrZWwiLCJzdWIiOiIwN2MzNTU5MS04NTRmLTQ1ZWItYjMxZS0zYWViNDFlOTllZWYiLCJ0eXAiOiJJRCIsImF6cCI6InNrZWwiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1OTkzMzkwODcsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiIzMTBiYTFjOC1hOWQyLTQ1YmYtODljYy1jN2M2MDJiNmU3MWYiLCJhY3IiOiIwIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIn0.signature
2020-09-06 00:43:36.013 TRACE 52892 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   :        refresh_token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJjMjZjNmE5Ny1kYmU5LTQwMjktYjg2Zi0yNDk3ZjAyYmNmMWIifQ.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.signature
```

I am using this Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    .... with dependencyManagement: ...
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Does anybody have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you have any configuration class for Oauth? It could be because of orders of your filters

Comment: I can't tell with the information you provide. Sorry for the vague suggestions. You may want to check if you didn't set up some redirect action in the authentication flow. You may want to check your session lifetime (what if it's only a millisecond ?). You may want to look for network issues. The auth server should be using HTTPS, using port 8081 may lead to problems.

Comment: I clean-installed everything, out-of-the-box, I haven't done any customisation or configuration, apart from what I included in the original message.

Comment: I did find a workaround: I used Spring Security and wrote a configuration class that extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Not ideal, but it is what is it.